# How to do port forwarding for VPN server

Tags: windows, vpn, router, ip-address, site-to-site-vpn

Let say my workplace public IP is 111.222.111.222. And I have a pc inside this network, and the computer ip is 10.0.0.60. I installed a SFTP server inside this pc. And in my router, I do port forwarding to this pc for 1160. ( So that any request to 111.222.111.222 port 1160 will come to this PC )

So, when I went back to my home, I connect to internet and SFTP to my workplace PC, by using IP 111.222.111.222 and port 1160, also also the username and password I configured early, yes, I am successfully access to my workplace PC and I can add/remove file in the folder.

Now I would like to set up a VPN server in the workplace PC, I done set up it by referring to https://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/

As my understanding, If I want to connect to the VPN server from my home, I need the public IP, VPN username, and VPN password, 3 things. Now I am confuse, I no need to key in port number, If I do VPN connection with request to 111.222.111.222, how my workplace router will know this request is a VPN request to the PC? Since I didnt put any port request. I am hitting "connection failed with error 800", my client PC is window 7.

I believe that I am wrong with some configuration, because I am not able to connect to the VPN server from outside internet. But when I come back to workplace and connect the cable, I am able to make the VPN connection to the internal IP, which is 10.0.0.60.

From the website I mention just now, in the limitation there, it mention as follow: **You have to expose Windows and a port for the PPTP VPN server directly to the Internet, which is not ideal from a security standpoint. You should use a strong password and consider using a port that isn’t the default port.**

I believe I didnt do this part. As I didnt see anything I can do about this. Kindly advise on how to expose Windows and a port for the PPTP VPN server directly to the Internet.

Comment: The article you quoted actually lists the port to forward. You need to be aware that not all VPNs can be forwarded with port forwarding, as they do not use tcp or Udp (with ports).

Comment: In my case, do you know how can I connect to my created VPN server from outside internet?

Comment: The article claims you need to forward port 1723.